# How to know which Android API an APK was built against

Tags: android, build

When an APK is generated with a given API Level, is there a way to know which API level was used for compiling just having the APK file?

The minSdkVersion does not necessarily match the API Level used for compiling the project, it is just a note for the Android installer to block the app if minSdkVersion > current version

Answer (score 2):

```
BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE;
```

and

```
getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(...).
```

will give us:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
...
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="...">
```

the versionCode, 1 in this example.

The API Level used to compile the .apk I could not find a way of consult it in runtime, but if you use **gradle** you can check it:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
...
}
```

if you are using **.iml**, configured with the IntelliJ project configurations GUI:

```
<component name="NewModuleRootManager" inherit-compiler-output="true">
    ...
    <orderEntry type="inheritedJdk" />
    ...
</component>
```

**project.properties**:

```
# This file is automatically generated by IntelliJ IDEA
# Project target.
target=Google Inc.:Google APIs:22
```

but since **build.gradle**, **project.iml** and **project.properties** aren't shipped with .apk I can't think of a way to get the compileSdkVersion in runtime or by unzipping the .apk

Comment: This will just get the version code for the package (app) this code is running in

Answer (score 2):

This is another way to get the `targetSdkVersion` and the `versionCode` of my application:

```
try {
            PackageInfo packageInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
            int versionCode = packageInfo.versionCode;
            int targetSdkVersion = packageInfo.applicationInfo.targetSdkVersion;

        }
        catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
```

using `Android Studio`, the values are defined into my `build.gradle` file

```
   defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tuna.hello.androidstudioapplication"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 12
        versionName "1.0"
    }
```

Comment: With the packageInfo you get all your defaultConfig (if using gradle) or manifest <uses-sdk> information but not the compileSdkVersion which is the desired information.

Answer (score 1):

Everything that you could get should be on ApplicationInfo that you get from PackageManager, so you should get ApplicationInfo and then see what you can get out of it, i.e.:

```
getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(...).targetSdkVersion
```

Reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo.html

Check in the "Fields"section of the reference. Have a look at "sourceDir" field.

I hope this is of any help for you, and please vote up/down whatever helped/missdirected you.

Best regards.

Comment: This does not answer his question .targetSdkVersion, as stated, it is just a note for the Android installer to block some phones in PlayStore. API level it's delivered by .versionCode. Check my answer.

Comment: @GuilhE your answer returns whatever code you set in the manifest, which is arbitrary and non SDK related. Check here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html#versionCode

Comment: That's correct, I was wrong, getPackageManager() will give the apk information we used in the manifest. Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT
```

Comment: that gives you the phone SDK version, not the .apk

Comment: SDK is the Android API level. I believe this is what he is asking for.

Comment: I think he's asking which API level was used to compile the .apk not the API level the phone uses. Maybe I've interpreted wrong

Comment: you are correct on that, this is the running api level of the phone

Answer (score 0):

How to know which Android API your application is running:

```
int myAPI = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
```

How to know the APK´s versionCode was built:

```
String versionCode = ctx.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(ctx.getPackageName(), 0).versionName;
```

Note: `ctx` is the application Context.

**But to be more specific, change the extension of your APK file to .zip, and extract the `Manifest.xml` then you can see the `versionCode`, `minSdkVersion`, `targetSdkVersion` etc...**

Comment: Build.VERSION.SDK_INT; will give the phone current API level

Comment: Yes i know, i think the best solution for this question is opening the AndroidManifest.xml of the application directly. ;)

Comment: Do you know if is it possible to check it in runtime? Btw, with gradle you can set compileSdkVersion but not in the manifest. So the best way it's to open build.gradle or project.iml

Comment: I think this is in runtime: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30337443/how-to-know-which-android-api-an-apk-was-built-against/30338324#30338324